# duplicable database

Tags: php, sql, copy, duplicates

Is there a way that i can copy my database (a) from localhost and place it intro database (b) localhost?

I was thinking mb php has some manually (on refresh page opera refresh page every 1 seconds) or automatic  php get from db(a) post to db (b) anything like this possible ?

What i need it for ...in to db (a) i store new members and every 30 minutes db (a) deletes itself, but db (b) its always full.  So even if myweb.com gets hacked no one knows to hack myweb1.com if that makes any sense.  One website hides the other

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This question is written very vaguely and broad, and as such will likely be closed.  I would suggest that what you are looking for will need to be implemented/created by you.  So I recommend coding something and when you run into an error, post it here and we'll help.

Comment: You should add some additional information about your sql servers.

Comment: Thx I did not know what I had to look for now I have found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very hard to answer your question becouse we dont know much about your web and SQL servers.

If you have 2 SQL servers or 2 instances, or 2 separate databases you can easy create [SQL JOB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)
and schedlue it to execute every 30 min or so.

Job would be simple to select data from DB(a) and insert them in DB(b) then delete records in DB(a) .. you need to make it in [SQL transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) so new records added in DB(a) when you move records dont get deleteded

Comment: Thx looks like a new challenge